# Can a static class be set as delegate for a UItextfield (Objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my current project I have a few viewcontrollers that use a UItextfield. As of now I have all the viewcontrollers set as delegates for the textField. However, I have all the same code for each of the viewcontrollers (at least for the UItextfield delegate methods). Is there a way I can just create a static class and set that as the delegate for all the UItextfields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using two ways.

1. Once create a singleton class that can handle your delegates and assign the singleton instance as your delegate.
2. You can inherit the UITextField say `myTextField` and implement all the delegate methods which you want to override. For all the instances where you want to use TextField and have the custom behavior use `myTextField`.